# NSArray release crashes app

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I am trying to "tokenize" my data that I get from my text file.

When I am doing this, I get an error like this:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x844c730: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

The code I use looks like this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mydata" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *rawText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
//No error was caused by above line
NSArray *tmp = [rawText componentsSeparatedByString:@"##@@"];
NSString *title = @"";
NSString *detail = @"";
for(int i = 0; i < [tmp count]-1; i++)
{
    NSArray *base = [[tmp objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"##"];
    title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@$$%@",title,[base objectAtIndex:0]];
    detail = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@$$%@ | %@ | %@",
              title,
              [base objectAtIndex:0],
              [base objectAtIndex:1],
              [base objectAtIndex:2]
              ];
    [base release];
}
[tmp release];
```

It must be this part of the code, since if I comment this piece out, it works fine.

Reading the error it says `set a breakpoint` which I have no idea to put that in `malloc_error_break`

What is wrong in my memory management doing?

*Or else how can I split up the string in some other way?*

Comment: Are you sure it's the NSArray release causing the crash? Does the program leave an EXC_BAD_ACCESS or something at that line?

Comment: Ah, it does leave a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` but not there, in the main.m

Comment: The EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main.m is not useful. You should always add a breakpoint on thrown exceptions using the add button in the breakpoint navigator/sidebar. This will cause the debugger to break on the line that threw the exception not main.m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got `tmp` from `componentsSeparatedByString:`.  Since that selector doesn't start with "alloc" or "new" or "copy" or "mutableCopy", and since you didn't do `[tmp retain]`, you don't own `tmp`.  So you shouldn't do `[tmp release]`.

Same for `base`.

Comment: I am still trying to get my head around the memory stuff. Been doing Java for 3 years :/ - thanks!

Comment: If you google for *objective-c memory management*, you will find a number of good intros (including Apple's).  But if you can possibly get away with requiring iOS 5, ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) will make it even easier.

Answer (score 1):

Base and temp are `autorelease` objects so you should not release that objects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to release `base`. It's already autoreleased.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to release array base without allocating it.
NSArray *base = [[tmp objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"##"]; didn't allocate memory for base.You don't need [base release];
 until it is allocated.

Comment: Of course `componentsSeparatedByString:` allocates memory. But the array returned is autoreleased. That just means that the current autorelease pool will release the object for you later.